# return all object created in loop

Tags: php, mysqli

i am new to php OOP, i am trying to select using OOP, i have a

```
class page {
    var $title;

    function settitle($title){ $this->title = $title;}
}
```

now

```
class model {

    connection $done ;


    function getAllPages(){
        $query3 = "select * from pages";
        $result3 = mysqli_query($this->con,$query3);
        while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){
            $page = new Page;
            $page->setP_title($rows['p_title']);
        }
        return $page;
    }
}
```

now

```
class controller{
    function indexAllPage(){
        $pages = $this->conn->getAllPages();
        include('allpages.php');
    }
}
```

now

VIEW
allpages.php

Comment: Please format the question correctly. I understand you are a new user, but it shouldnt be that hard. SO has really great formatting tools.

Comment: Have you tried runing indexAllPage? And you have mistake: $page->setP_title($rows['p_title']);

Comment: If you are going to implement your own mvc, create an output method in your view class and change your get method in model to accept parameters and based on it, return a proper result (like mentioned in bitWorking's answer) then just call the output and it cares of things

Answer (score 1):

You need an array if you want to return more than one page:

```
$pages = array();
while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){
    $page = new Page;
    $page->settitle($rows['p_title']);
    $pages[] = $page;
}
return $pages;
```

UPDATE:

```
$pages = $this->conn->getAllPages();

// $pages is now an array, so you have to loop through it or get a specific index

// get first page from array
$page = $pages[0];

// loop through it
foreach ($pages as $page) {
    $title = $page->getTitle();
}
```

Comment: hi, sorry about putting the code in wrong format. next i will be carefull. But actually i have tried doing the same thing what you have mentioned, but the problem is pages[] is an array and $page is an object so its giving me fatal error cannot use object as a array.

Comment: That is a different issue. The answer supplied here answers this question.

Comment: I have found the solution. here is the code. May be it will help some one else also.
    function getAllPages(){
    $query3 = "select * from pages";
    $result3 = mysqli_query($this->con,$query3);
    $pages = array();
    $num = 0;
    $page = new Page();
    while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){
    $page->setP_title($rows['p_title']);
    $pages[$num] = $page->getP_title();
    $num++;
    }
    return $pages;
    }

But thanks soo much for everyone who have answered my question. Thanks this really a very good platform for bignners like me.